# Converting data in text file to csv tables

Tags: csv, conversion, table

My data in a text file have the below format today

```
HKL1234/2, R1B
HKL1274/2, R4E
HREF457-74, R1A
```

I need to present this data in excel file in two different columns like below:

```
Product            Revision
HKL1234/2          R1B
HKL1274/2          R4E
HREF457-74         R1A
```

How can I do this in bash script?
would you please help me with my challenge.

Comment: Your input looks like a CSV file. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158288/330217 You might have to prepend the heading line before converting the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert CSV to XLS file on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158254/convert-csv-to-xls-file-on-linux) (Link to the same question as in my previous comment; the comment was added automatically by my vote to close as a duplicate.)

Comment: You could simply import the text file with Excel's own [text import wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything to load CSV data into Excel - it perfectly able to read these files.

So assuming you have `data.txt` with a contents shown in the original post:

```
HKL1234/2, R1B
HKL1274/2, R4E
HREF457-74, R1A
```

All you need is to add a header line and rename file:

```
echo "Product, Revision" > data.csv
cat data.txt >> data.csv
```

First command will create a `data.csv` file with a header line. Second will add contents of the original data file into the newly created `data.csv`.

Now, just copy that `data.csv` to a windows machine, and double-click on it in the Explorer - the CSV extension is by default registered for Excel. If you ruined that - just "Open with..." or open Excel first, and open the file in it. However you do it - Excel knows how deal with .csv files.

Comment: it works perfectly. Thank you very much